# Chinese remainder theorem, how can I prove it?

Tags: group-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem

I want to show that $\mathbb Z/pq\mathbb Z\cong \mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z/q\mathbb Z$ where $(p,q)=1$. I consider the morphism $$[a]_{pq}\longmapsto ([a]_p,[a]_q).$$

If I have the injectivity, then, I'll have the surjectivity (since the two set has same cardinality).

**method 1 :** So $$([a]_p,[a]_q)=0\implies p\mid a\wedge q\mid a\underset{(p,q)=1}{\implies} pq\mid a.$$
How can I get $a=0$ ?

**method 2**

I consider $$([a]_p,[b]_q)\longmapsto [ab]_{pq}.$$
So $$[ab]_{pq}=0\implies pq\mid ab$$
and since $(p,q)=1$, we get $p\mid ab$ and $q\mid ab$. How can I conclude that $a=b=0$ ?

Comment: You do realize that in $\mathbb Z/pq\mathbb Z$, $a=0$ exactly means $pq|a$ ?

Answer (score 1):

In your first method, if $pq\mid a$, it mean that $a=0$ (in $\mathbb Z/pq\mathbb Z$). So, it's finish.

In your second method, your map is even not a group homomorphism since $$\varphi\Big[([a],[b])+([c],[d])\Big]=[(a+c)(b+d)]\neq [ab]+[cd]=\varphi([a],[b])+\varphi([c],[d]).$$